# Multiple dependent dropdown menus

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am stuck with multiple dynamic dropdowns. So here is the problem I try to solve. I have the following four example tables stored in a database and want to access the values dynamically. 
Dropdown 2 is dependent on Dropdown 1, Dropdown 4 is dependent on 2 and 3.

```
| ID  | name   | percent |      | ID  | name    | languageValue | 100 | 75  | 501 |
| --- | ------ | ------- |      | --- | ------- | ------------- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 100%   | 100     |      | 1   | English | english       | y   | y   | n   |
| 3   | 75%    | 75      |      | 2   | German  | german        | y   | n   | n   |
| 2   | 50% 1  | 501     |      | 3   | French  | french        | n   | n   | y   |
Table 1 (Dropdown 1)            Table 2 (Dropdown 2)

| ID  | CoreSubjectName | CoreSubjectValue |   | ID  | MinorSubjectName | MinorSubjectValue |
| --- | --------------- | ---------------- |   | --- | ---------------- | ----------------- |
| 1   | Maths           | maths            |   | 1   | English          | english           |
| 2   | Politics        | politics         |   | 2   | Politics         | politics          |
| 3   | Chemics         | chemics          |   | 3   | Chemics          | chemics           |
Table 3 (Dropdown 3)                           Table 4 (Dropdown 4)
```

I retrieve the values for the first dropdown as the following. (I leave out the closing tags).

```
<select name="percent" id ="percent" onchange="getPercent(this.value);">
    <option value="">Choose Percent</option>
<?php
   $PercentPost = $_POST["percent"];
   $PercentQuery = "SELECT percent, name FROM percentTable";
   $results=mysqli_query($conn, $anteilQuery);
   //loop
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
       echo '<option value="'.$row[percent].'">'.$row[name].'</option>';
   }
?>
<select name="language" id="language">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
```

And the js-ajax for filling the second Dropdown:

```
function getPercent(val){
        //ajax function
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "form.php",
            data: "percent="+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#language").html(data);
            }
        });

    }
```

form.php contains this snippet so far:

```
$PercentPost = $_POST["percent"];
if (!empty($_POST["percent"])) {

    $query="SELECT name, languageValue FROM table2 WHERE `$PercentPost`='y'";

    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row[languageValue].'">'.$row[name].'</option>';
    }
}
```

This works fine, but now I don't know how to fill dropdown 4 dynamically. In Dropdown 4 the selected  values of 2 and 3 should not be selectable. I know it has to be done with ajax of js, but I have no clue how.

Can someone help me out? 
Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you'll load DropDown 4 as disabled (`disabled` attribute) or invisible (`style="display:none;"`).

I'll add to your DropDown 2 and 3 a default value like select... with value 0 or -1 (see next PHP code for example)

Then I'll add an `onchange` attribute for the DropDown 2 and 3, they will both call the same js function :

```
function loadDD4Values(){
    if ($('#language').val() <> 0 && $('#coreSubject').val() <> 0){
         //ajax function
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "form.php", //You can detect what to do based on params, or have a different PHP page
            data: "language="+$('#language').val() + "&coreSubject=" + $('#coreSubject').val() ,
            success: function(data){
                $("#minorSubject").html(data);
                $('#minorSubject').style.display = '';//or remove attribute disabled, also if you want you can disable/hide DropDown 2 and 3 here
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#minorSubject').style.display = 'none'; //or add attribute disabled
    }

    //Also here you can decide what to do if the user modify DropDown 2 or 3  for example, reset the DropDown 4 values, or just the selected one:
    $('#minorSubject').selectedValue = 0;
}
```

Then your PHP could be :

```
if( isset($_POST['percent']) ){
    // Your code from the DropDown 2
}else if (isset($_POST['language']) && isset($_POST['coreSubject'])){
    //You didn't had sql injection protection in your question code !!!
    $language = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['language']);
    $coreSubject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['coreSubject']);

    $query="SELECT ... FROM minorSubject WHERE `$language`='...' AND `$coreSubject`='...'";

    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    echo '<option value="0">Select ...</option>'; // A default row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row[ID].'">'.$row[...].'</option>'; //Use ID for the value, It's made for that
    }
}
```

The code as not been tested so there will be some typos... , adapt it to your own usage.

Don't hesitate to ask for complementary information.

Comment: Wow, super cool! It works like a charm and I learned new stuff! Thank you very much! But how about adding some additional conditions like: e.g. 75% is not allowed to choose a minor subject? Would I add these special cases to my php and connect the loadDD4Value-function with the first dropdown as well? Or would it be better to create forms for each case in the php?

Comment: Yeah, I'll read the percent value (or its id) in the `loadDD4Value` (I'll just read its value when updating 2 or 3, dont need to add the `loadDD4Value` to 1's onChange event) .

Then I'll pass the 3  parameters to the same php page, same as before : If just `percent` is set, I load the 2 and 3 dropdown, if `percent`,`language` and `coreSubject` are set I load (return values) the 4th dropdown (only if `percent` is <> `75%`). 

In js I'll then check that if 0 options (or just the default one) are returned by the php page, I'll disable or hide the 4th dropdown.

Comment: Also, I don't know if you added that 75% condition just for the example. But It's always better to use the percent_id in your SQL query and have a way to determine in your database if the SQL request return values or not ;)